# how to match both fields are not exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

1. I was trying to use `$and` to express both fields are empty
2. Here is the code

```
    db.tweets_v2.aggregate({
      {match:{$and:[{replyto_id:$exist:false},{replyto_id:$exist:false}]}
    });
```

Comment: It still did not work, could you please give me the full of the code? thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few fixes,

- $exist should be `$exists`
- missed {} brackets before and after in `$exists`
- match should be `$match`
- aggregation stages start from `[]` not {}

```
db.tweets_v2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { replyto_id: { $exists: false } },
        { replyfrom_id: { $exists: false } } // change your second field name
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vRYBRisdhAK)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `$and` is not needed, this one will also work:

```
db.tweets_v2.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        replyto_id: { $exists: false } ,
        replyfrom_id: { $exists: false }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding, this one is also really helpful as well.